# How can I bulk add text to only the lines that end with numbers in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor, rich-text-editor, bulk

I'm using Sublime to do some simple text editing.

Now I have a bunch of URLs and I have to add text at those who end with numbers, but not those URLs who end with text.

How can I do this in bulk?

eg.

```
http://www.example.com/pt/abcde/123456
http://www.example.com/pt/fghi/789012/addtext
http://www.example.com/pt/jklmn/345678/addtext
http://www.example.com/pt/opqr/901234
http://www.example.com/pt/stuvz/567890/addtext
```

I need it to be

```
http://www.example.com/pt/abcde/123456/addtext
http://www.example.com/pt/fghi/789012/addtext
http://www.example.com/pt/jklmn/345678/addtext
http://www.example.com/pt/opqr/901234/addtext
http://www.example.com/pt/stuvz/567890/addtext
```

I have thousand of lines so I'd like to bulk edit only the lines that end with numbers.

At the moment I'm able to bulk edit all the lines using the function **ctrl+shift+L** and then paste the `/addtext`, but this will add the text to all the lines, resulting in a double `/addtext` to the lines that have already the `/addtext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a regex to do the job. This would work for example:

Find: `^(http.*/\d+)$`

Replace with: `$1/addtext`

[image]

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not familiar with regex, could you explain briefly what command does what?

Comment: `^(http.*/\d+)$` matches: any string that starts with "http", followed by any number of characters (`.*`), and which ends with a slash (`/`) followed by one or more digits (`\d+`). `$1` in the "Replace With" field means "take the string that was just found and insert it there".